# How to create a control use native client

Tags: google-chrome, npapi, google-nativeclient

I want to create a control, like edit window in chrome, and npapi is not support, and now can use naci instead of it, but i can not find any control in naci sdk, anyone know that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "control". If you mean you want to use activex controls then you can't

Comment: @taxilian thank you for your reply, then, I want to create a ui like edit window in web using nacl, how to do it ？

Comment: does have a third library to support it?

Comment: Nacl has drawing libraries; they may be frameworks which support them that you could use.  I don't know.